# how to make updateGL() realtime in QT

Tags: c++, qt, opengl

I wonder if calling updateGL() in fixed timer intervals may slow down the rendering process. So, I want to try making the render real time. I do not the function to make it execute automatically. Anyone knows that?

secondly, I commented updateGL() in my program, CPU usage reduced to 1% and 0%. Now, when I click on the display widget it jumps to 14%, why? isn't GPU doing all the rendering job? if yes why CPU jumps to 14? how can I resolve this?

Comment: For the CPU usage, no, it isn't the GPU that does *all* the job. The CPU has still to execute the commands to pass to the GPU, and sometimes wait for synchronisation (and also performs the logic of your application, if any). Nevertheless, if your scene is really simple, 14% is definitely not normal. Make sure you are not drawing at more than 60fps which doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 13):

Yes, you can make it realtime, with no tearing (e.g., redrawing at exactly 60fps, the refresh rate of your monitor).

For this, you have to enable V_sync, and using a `QTimer timer;` of interval 0. Enabling V_sync will make the automatically called `swapBuffers()` command to CPU-wait for the vertical refresh signal from your monitor. Then, the timer will actually be synchronized with the monitor refresh rate.

A related info can be found here: https://www.qt.io/blog/2010/12/02/velvet-and-the-qml-scene-graph. Note the `QGLFormat::setSwapInterval(1)` to enable V_sync, if not done automatically by your driver settings:

```
class MyGLWidget: public QGLWidget
{
    // ...
private:
    QTimer timer;
}

QGLFormat desiredFormat()
{
    QGLFormat fmt;
    fmt.setSwapInterval(1);
    return fmt;
}

MyGLWidget::MyGLWidget() :
    QGLWidget(desiredFormat())
{
    // Configure the timer
    connect(&timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateGL()));
    if(format().swapInterval() == -1)
    {
        // V_blank synchronization not available (tearing likely to happen)
        qDebug("Swap Buffers at v_blank not available: refresh at approx 60fps.");
        timer.setInterval(17);
    }
    else
    {
        // V_blank synchronization available
        timer.setInterval(0);
    }
    timer.start();
}
```

In parallel, you can run a `QElapsedTimer` to measure how much time has passed between two drawing (normally approx 16.6ms), and use this information to update your scene, for instance.

Comment: i added     this->format().setSwapInterval(1); in the constructor and swapbuffers() at the end of paintGL() function. but it had no effect. how to make it render 60fps?

Comment: @user1596226 Two things: you shouldn't call `this->format().setSwapInterval(1);` but rather create a QGLFormat with this swap interval and pass it to the constructor of your `QGLWidget`. Then, you shouldn't call `swapBuffers()` at all: as I said, it is called automatically after your `paintGL()` :) Are you able to measure and display the time between each paintGL() by using a `QElapsedTimer`? This will be very helpful to understand what's going on.

Comment: could you please write it for me, I do not knw exactly how to add this flag to constructor.

Comment: @user1596226 see my edit. If it doesn't work (ie show the debug message), it means you have to configure something in your driver, that can overrive OpenGL application settings.

Comment: @user1596226, you should really make some effort on your own and be more descriptive on your problems otherwise there is nothing anyone could do to help you. Does it compiles? Is the qDebug() message displayed? What are the optained frame rate? Have you checked if V_sync was enabled or not in you driver? etc...

Comment: it write the qDebug that it is not available. about checking V_sync availability on the driver, I do not know how to do that.

Comment: Then Google it :) It depends on your OS, driver, etc. And anyway you really should first of all check your frame rate, and test with different timer intervals. Also, if you found my answer any helpful, you should consider upvoting it, and if it ever eventually solves your issue, accept it. I'm telling you this since I see you never accepted any of the answers from your previous 28 questions, which is very surprising, and is not likely to encourage people to help you.

Comment: i was not able to upvote previously. since i myself did not have enough votes to do that.tnx for your help.

Comment: @user1596226 oops, forgot about this privilege thing, sorry about that.

Comment: @Boris That's a helpful one. But I have a problem. I put a `QElapsedTimer` to measure the time between consecutive updates, but it shows absolutely stochastic values like 3,22,5,0,9,31,15,17,1 etc. I'm guessing the root of the problem to be that I'm not using any low-level openGL functions. Neither do I have the `paintGL`, `updateGL` etc. setup. Instead, I have overridden the `paintEvent(QPaintEvent *)` event and connected the timer's `timeout` to `update()`. Is this the cause of the problem? Can you help?

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder Hi! This question/answer is only relevant if you are using a QGLWidget (which is now deprecated anyway since Qt 5.4). If you are not using OpenGL then I don't know. You might try to call repaint() instead of update() if you want more control on when stuff are drawn: repaint() draws instantly, while update() is smarter and waits for the "best moment", possibly merging several update() together. Note that update() is the recommended method unless you know what you're doing :)

Comment: @Boris Hi! But I'm using `QGLWidget` (somehow `QOpenGLWidget` doesn't allow me to create a top level transparent window). Umm... could you have a look at [this question](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/62941-How-to-achieve-vsync-using-only-QPainter-on-a-QGLWidget?p=278774). Yeah, it was me who asked this question. But I've got no replies yet. Maybe you can help. :)

Comment: @Boris Was my question not clear? Do you want me to rephrase it?

Comment: @ThePeacefulCoder Sorry, I was just slow to answer. Can you post your question on SO then comment again here to notify me you posted it? (I'd better answer here than in the Qt forum). Quick thoughts: I think you shouldn't use QGLWidget or QOpenGLWidget if you're not using native openGL calls, since these classes are really meant for that. If you are drawing with a QPainter anyway, it is possible that Qt does it's own stuff under the hood that prevents you to have full control over when things are drawn, and therefore over the refresh rate.