# Syncing image display with screen refresh rate

Tags: opengl, pyqt, pyqt4, pyopengl

**What the program does**: Using [PyQt4](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) to display images (simple jpg/png files).

**The objective**: Have an image displayed/drawn on the screen in sync with the screen's refresh rate.

A *pseudo-code* sample of what i would like to achieve:

```
pixmap = set_openGL_pixmap(myPixmap) 

draw_openGL_pixmap(pixmap) 

doSomthingElse()
```

Ideally, the `draw_openGL_pixmap(pixmap)` function should only return after the screen has refreshed and the image is displayed. Than `doSomthingElse()` will be executed immediately after the image was really drawn.

**What i've tried so far**:

- Using [PyQt's](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) [`QApplication.processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) after setting a pixmap to a PyQt label **:** This doesn't seem to to the trick, since it doesn't deal with syncing with the screen's refresh rate.
- Using [QGLFormat.setSwapInterval()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qglformat.html#setSwapInterval) **:** Even though this should work as the documentation suggests, PyQt doesn't draw the image on the screen until [`QApplication.processEvents()`](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents) is called, or until the control is returned to the application's event loop (i.e., when all of the functions i called have returned and the GUI is waiting for new events).
- Using [QGraphicsView](http://www.rkblog.rk.edu.pl/w/p/qgraphicsview-and-qgraphicsscene/) - Even though the image is rendered using an OpenGL widget, it is only visible once it's parent is displayed, so the actual time of display still depends on [PyQt's](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) event loop.
- Using [QWidget.repaint()](http://pyqt.sourceforge.net/Docs/PyQt4/qwidget.html#repaint) - The `repaint()` method will cause the image to be displayed immediately. However, I don't think when `repaint()` is called, it waits until a screen refresh event before it returns.

**Summarizing:**
How can i make [PyQt](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) draw the image on the screen (in a widget) at the exact moment i issue the command, in sync with the screen refresh rate, regardless of [PyQt's](http://www.riverbankcomputing.co.uk/software/pyqt/intro) event loop.

Comment: see also http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167194/how-to-make-updategl-realtime-in-qt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks to Trialarion's comment to my question, I found the solution [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167194/how-to-make-updategl-realtime-in-qt).

For anyone interested, here's the python code that displays images in sync with the screen refresh rate:

```py
import sys
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtOpenGL import *

app = QApplication(sys.argv)

# Use a QGLFormat with the swap interval set to 1
qgl_format = QGLFormat()
qgl_format.setSwapInterval(1)

# Construct a QGLWidget using the above format
qgl_widget = QGLWidget(qgl_format)

# Set up a timer to call updateGL() every 0 ms
update_gl_timer = QTimer()
update_gl_timer.setInterval(0)
update_gl_timer.start()
update_gl_timer.timeout.connect(qgl_widget.updateGL)

# Set up a graphics view and a scene
grview = QGraphicsView()
grview.setViewport(qgl_widget)
scene = QGraphicsScene()
scene.addPixmap(QPixmap('pic.png'))
grview.setScene(scene)

grview.show()

sys.exit(app.exec_())
```